# I have 1800 teradata views whose table name needs to be found from which the view is being created from

Tags: sql, view, relational-database, teradata, sql-view

I have an eod request for which i need to find out tables from which 1800 views have been created using teradata.
Firing show view for every views and then finding the table seems to be a very cumbersome task.
I am just wondering if there is any query using which i can just pass the dbc.view_name and the dbc.table_name using which those views are created can be resulted in the output.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest DBQL: If objects are not logged, enable `begin query logging with no columns objects` temporarily. Create a script running `select 1 from myview where 1=0;` for each view. Wait for DBQL to get flushed and then you got all tables in `dbc.QryLogObjectsV`.